# How to extend a token in MS Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm authenticating to Dynamics using the following code:

```
public async Task<String> GetAuthenticationToken(string uri, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
AuthenticationParameters ap = 
AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(new Uri(uri)).Result;
var creds = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ap.Authority);
AuthenticationResult result = await 
authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ap.Resource, creds);
return result.AccessToken;
}
```

It works great and returns a AuthenticationResult that includes:

```
AccessToken: The usual long string
AccessTokenType : Bearer
ExpiresOn : DateTime 1 hour from now
ExtendedExpiresOn : Datetime 3 days from now
Authority : A login.microsoft.com URL
```

The issues is that I don't know how to refresh the token so that I can continue working.  Is there an easy call that I can make that will extend it for another hour?

Comment: Any special reason you are using the web api from .NET?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, not 100% sure about code, havent tested

```
 private static string GetToken(TraceWriter log)
    {
        lock (tokenlock)
        {
            if (DateTime.UtcNow >= ExpireDate)
            {

                var clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance, false);
                AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(organizationUrl, clientcred);
                token = result.AccessToken;
                ExpireDate = result.ExpiresOn.DateTime;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }
            return token;
        }
    }
```